# Можно ли как то nodejs приложение скомпилировать в .exe с поддержкой 32bit?

Tags: node.js, компиляция

Сейчас использую pkg, но он компилирует приложение с поддержкой x64, x86

Comment: IA-32, i386, x86, x86-32 — это всё разные обозначения одной и той же архитектуры intel-совместимых 32-битных процессоров.

Answer (score 0):

Да, воспользуйтесь Electron JS https://www.electronjs.org/

```
npm run electron:build -- --ia32
```

Замечу, что x86 = 32bit